# ULTRA X3 D0409 1000W PSU and high 3.3v rail voltage

Tags: power-supply

I just got ULTRA X3 D0409 1000W PSU for a rig which I'm building and before putting it in, as always, I have it checked with PSU tester and came up that 3.3V rail voltage is going high (up to 4.1) but it will fluctuate after that between 3.7 and 4.0

I think going above 3.8V it should to trigger over-voltage protection in the PSU but it didn't.

Any thoughts on that? Is this can be adjusted by a resistor or something else?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Most likely it's not user adjustable.

Besides most power supplies need at least some load to keep it happily regulated.

Comment: "some load to keep it happily regulated"... often on the primary supply output, whichever output that that happens to be.  See datasheet.

Comment: It sounds like I need to connect it to the motherboard then...

Comment: The PSU tester should include a sufficient load, you should check if it does, or just place a 5-10 ohms resistor across 3.3V and see if it helps. If I were you, I would not test it on the motherboard if it stays above 4V. As far as I know, most 3.3V ICs specify a maximum working voltage of 3.6V. You don't want to damage the board.

Comment: Found a manual from year 2007 for the power supply, so I don't know of it is the same product or not. It requires minimum 4A load on 12V. That's 48 watts. I don't think any cheapo handheld PSU tester will provide that much load, it would require heat sinking and a fan. And 3.3 volt output overvoltage protection limit has a maximum of 4.5V. So either the power supply is not properly loaded (likely) or it is faulty (unlikely).